# How to filter the store views so that only information for mobile stores will be saved?

Tags: stores, magento-1.9.3.8

How to add a filter to the following piece of code

```
    foreach($this->getStores() as $_store {
         $storeName = $this->__($this->htmlEscape($_store->getName()));
         $storeId = $_store->getId();
         $storeCode = $_store->getCode();
    }
```

in a way that magento will only get that info for mobile store views? The code for all mobile store views is `$mageRunCode .= '_mobile'`

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: As the code is already, I would get the name, id and code of all store views (including desktop stores), so my question is how to adjust the code in a way that I get that info only for mobiel stores views which code is $mageRunCode .= '_mobile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is as follows:

```
        foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
           foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
              $stores = $group->getStores();
              foreach ($stores as $_store) {

                 $storeCode = $_store->getCode();
                 $storeId = $_store->getId();
                 $storeName = $this->__($this->htmlEscape($_store->getName()));
                 if (strpos($storeCode, '_mobile') !== false) {
                    if ($_store->getIsActive()) {
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to adjust the store below way**:

```
foreach($this->getStores() as $_store {
     $storeId = $_store->getId();
     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
     // after that get information of that store.
}
```

Comment: Hi Prasanta. The foreach loop that I pasted in the post is part of a dropdown that should only get the information from the mobile store views (identified by the code $mageRunCode .= '_mobile' ) so I want to know how to create a check that would only get that info for the mobile store views

Comment: Please provide the actual code to see how you are trying to do?